# Moving nested HTML dom nodes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom

I have a DOM tree structure similar to the following

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='item'>1</div>
        <div class='item'>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='item'>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='item'>4</div>
        <div class='item'>5</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='item'>6</div>
        <div class='item'>7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which renders out to this
[image: actual]
Here is the code that I have created showing the above result

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {}

.item {
  background-color: #1d8ed2;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='cell'>
    <div class='item'>1</div>
    <div class='item'>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='cell'>
    <div class='item'>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='cell'>
    <div class='item'>4</div>
    <div class='item'>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class='cell'>
    <div class='item'>6</div>
    <div class='item'>7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to move the elements in vanilla javascript in such a way where
the items move in this pattern.
[image: expected movement pattern]

And the final rendering should look like this expected result
[image: expected]

The tricky part here is the way they are nested in the cells and rows

Ive tried this but the expected result is not the desired outcome

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
if (cells.length > 0) {
  cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
    if (cell.children.length == 2) {
      return;
    }

    if (cells[index + 1]) {
      const itemToMove = cells[index + 1].children[0];
      cell.appendChild(itemToMove);
    }
  })
}
```

[image: not desired result]

Comment: the result seems random, what's the logic?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev the expected result can be thought of as essentially shifting the items to the left and up to the right like a ladder type pattern when there is a missing item

Comment: _"Which renders out to this"_ - please show a proper [mre] that includes the CSS you apply there, to get it rendered like this.

Comment: This would be a lot easier - and quite simple, using `display: grid` - without all the nesting, can the HTML be changed, or is it necessarily formed that way?

Comment: @CBroe ive updated the question to include a JSFiddle example, i hope that helps

Comment: @DavidThomas unfortunately the HTML cannot be changed, so i believe this will required a JS solution

Comment: Select all of the contents, then place them in the rows per two until you run out?

Comment: I tested your work on jsfiddle with the `js` snippet and it is giving the output that you are desiring

Comment: `display: grid` + `order` is the way to go here

Comment: @Raky it actually does not, 5 6 and 7 are all misplaced

Comment: @tacoshy unfortunately i cannot change the HTML markup so display grid wont work here

Comment: You can try by giving an `id` to each `cell`. You are finding difficulty because each cell has no `id`. In case they are generated randomly & dynamically, you may maintain a list of `id` that exist on the page and create/renum them as per need. This would also facilitate positioning the cells as per the `id` order.